# Assert empty textbox in testcafe

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, automation, testcafe

I am validating if the text box is empty or not. I am not sure what am I doing wrong here.

```
Page Object method
async getTextVal(){
  await this.t.selectText(this.editor) //selecting the text box
  return this.editor.innerText; //fetching the value in the textbox      
}
TestCase
await t.expect(element.getTextVal()).eql(''); //assert statement
```

the getTextVal works fine if there is a value present. But checking empty value it fails

Comment: Hello. What error are you getting? (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: 1) Attempted to run assertions on a Promise object. Did you forget to
      await it? If not, pass "{ allowUnawaitedPromise: true }" to the
      assertion options. This is what i am seeing. I tried "{ allowUnawaitedPromise: true }" but no luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
Page Object method
async getTextVal(){
  await this.t.selectText(this.editor) //selecting the text box
  return await this.editor.innerText; //fetching the value in the textbox      
}
TestCase
await t.expect(await element.getTextVal()).eql(''); //assert statement
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, without a method just a selector this can be done like so:

```
await t.expect(selector.innerText).eql('');
```

You can also setup your selector in a page object file:

```
import { Selector, t } from "testcafe";

class PageObjectFile {
    constructor() {
        // input field, this could be many different styles of selectors / frameworks
        this.inputField = Selector('.class-input-element');
        this.inputFieldTwo = Selector('#id-input-element');
    }
}

export default PageObjectFile;
```

And your test file like this:

```
import PageObjectFile from "/PageObjectFile";

let pageObjectFile = new PageObjectFile();

fixture `Tests input field is empty`
    .page(`https://examplepage.com`)


test(`User see's an empty input field`, async t => {
     await t.expect(pageObjectFile.inputField.innerText).eql('');
});
```